# Как самому написать функцию scanf?

Tags: c++, c

Нужно написать свою функцию, которая будет считывать только данные типа `long double`. Только не с помощью `scanf("%lf", &f)`, а путем создания своей функции

Например, `myscanf` (???), чтобы она могла читать только тип `long double`.

Comment: вы сами что-нибудь пробовали сделать?

Comment: @VladislavTikhomirov попробовал покопаться в документации. открыл stdio.h, думал оттуда что-то взять и поменять, но оказалось все сложнее

Comment: Вам не нужна документация по scanf (вообще нет смысла от scanf отталкиваться), вам нужно конвертировать набор вводимых символов (например, через getch, либо строку введенную через gets) в число. Это намного более простая и узкая задача.

Comment: Начните с дизайна. Вам нужно решить что такое число в тексте? Как начинается? Как завершается? Какие символы содержит? Затем наберите тестов которые подтверждают дизайн и прогоните их через scanf и проверьте как они согласуются с ваши дизайном. Потом напишите реализацию в виде псевдокода: как найти начало числа, как его читать по символам, как накапливать промежуточный результат, как завершить чтение. Последним пунктом пойдёт обработка ошибок.

Comment: @insolor понял, попробую

Comment: Можете покопаться в исходниках [strtod](http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/stdlib/strtod.c) (только она все равно внутренности scanf вызывает)